# Why do I get a timed out error in my due time job queue?

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, datastax

I have a queue-like column family which updates frequently around every hour. After a couple of hours or a day cassandra has a lot of read time outs.
I get this error message using Cassandra:

```
code=1100 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' 
responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." 
info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'LOCAL_ONE'}
```

Maybe I should not use Cassandra but Kafka or RabbitQM for these due time like queues. Any suggestions on what other solutions I should use? I am afraid the same problem will occur if I use Kafka etc.

Thanks

Comment: A query trace at this time would help diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally clear to me what "updates frequently around every hour" means, but since you mentioned the queue pattern, one might guess that it's timing out reading tombstoned cells. There are enough pitfalls around creating queue workloads in Cassandra that it has become a documented anti-pattern. [Here is a good article](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets) explaining the issue.

If you must use Cassandra for the queue, consider using or studying a project that is designed to mitigate the known pitfalls. [CassieQ](https://github.com/paradoxical-io/cassieq/wiki) is one example.

Comment: Thanks! If I don't use cassandra what are better alternatives to cassandra for the queue?

Comment: I need a delayed task queue but I don't know wether cassieQ or other solutions support this. I want to schedule my job queue after 1 hour or longer time periods. Any thoughts on this? thanks

Comment: I can't really do system design in SO comments. Generally, you would only choose to use Cassandra for a queue if you already have it in your environment and you don't to add more services. Outside of that, there are a plethora of queue/messaging options -- Kafka, ActiveMQ, ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ, MSMQ -- too many to list here.  The right choice for you will depend on your platform, system design, and deployment model.